# Execute cfquery after button press or behind the scenes action page?

Tags: coldfusion

My page creates a few random variables to pick prizes and winners for a drawing, and I want to write the prize winners and their prizes to a table after the winner clicks a button to claim the prize.

The problem is I want them to stay on the page so that a prize can be picked again if it isn't claimed.

The best solution I can come up with is an action page that the cfinput button references, but I don't want the action page to open up, I just want the cfquery on that page to run behind the scenes.

Here's an example of my query:

```
<cfquery name="updateQuantity" datasource="christmas">
UPDATE PRIZES
SET QUANTITY = QUANTITY - 1
WHERE prize_ID = #prizeID#
</cfquery>
```

I tried making my button a "submit" button and using cfif isDefined("form.Submit") to run the cfquery on the same page, but the submit button refreshes the page (which I don't want) and writes the next picked winner instead of the prizeID of the current session:

```
<cfform>
<cfinput name="submit" type="submit" value="Claim Your Prize!" onClick="">
</cfform>

<cfif isDefined("form.Submit")>
<cfquery name="updateQuantity" datasource="christmas">
UPDATE PRIZES 
SET QUANTITY = QUANTITY - 1 
WHERE prize_ID = #prizeID# </cfquery>
</cfif>
```

prizeID is determined by the randomly selected prize.

Comment: If you don't like Leigh's suggestion about ajax, you could put your action page into a 1 pixel iframe.  You'll still have to use js to change the content of the parent page.

Comment: No matter what approach you take, use query parameters and scope your variables.

Comment: First... don't use cfform.... second.. don't use the cfajax stuff.  I would use ajax for this but use jquery or something else.  Also, if you just decrementing a count on the query someone could exploit that in a second and reduce the count to zero.

Comment: @DanBracuk - The suggestion was from cherdt, not me. I just edited the answer to format the link.

Comment: This seems to be coming up a lot lately and I recently found a pretty good blog about it from Ben Forta. Read this - http://forta.com/blog/index.cfm/2012/11/25/When-Using-ColdFusion-No-Longer-Makes-Sense. Make sure you read it because the title is a bit mis-leading.

Answer (score 3):

Adam is correct.

While AJAX is what you're after, ColdFusion's AJAX related tags are not the way to go.

Take the time to learn JQuery and AJAX (it isn't too hard, and the CF community has some great examples and guides) and do it properly; with your example requirements, you should be up and running in no time.

That way you can properly manage any logging and error handling that you may need to as well. Good luck!

Comment: Whilst not directly answering the question as asked, I think it is a good answer. First: stop using CFFORM, try to use HTML & JQuery. Second: if you have problems with that (it's well-documented and not very difficult, so you should be OK)... revise your question or ask a new one and we can help you with the JQuery. There is a far bigger JS / JQuery community on Stack Overflow than CF people as well. So easier to get help.

Comment: Little late coming back to this, but is it possible to use jquery to post or send my variables to my action page for processing via a cfquery? Or can jquery/ajax run the cfquery for me on a button press? Having a hard time finding exactly what I need in all the ajax/jquery lingo out there.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like [ColdFusion.Ajax.submitForm](https://learn.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ColdFusion.Ajax.submitForm) would work for you.

In general, I think an AJAX request is what you are looking for.

Comment: Don't use ColdFusion's UI widgets. They're crap. Use standard markup and JQuery (etc). It makes for a better result, and is a transportable skill to learn. ColdFusion's UI wizards like CFFORM / CFAJAX are NOT useful skills to have in your arsenal.

Comment: Please don't ever suggest using ANY of the ColdFusion UI, JS, AJAX stuff. They tend to cause more problems than they are worth.

Comment: I do not use the CF UI stuff myself, but I find it annoying when every answer to a question about one technology involves jQuery. Sometimes you want to be able to solve a problem additional technology. Hence, a ColdFusion-only answer, and an agnostic comment pointing to a general class of answers.